# Firefox Javascript: Why does .all not work?

Tags: javascript, firefox, properties, undefined

In IE, I can go like:

```
var x = document.getElementById("header");

alert(x.all[0].tagName);
```

If I try that in Firefox, I get the error "all is undefined".

What is the Firefox equivalent of IE's `.all` property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.all` is a Microsoft-specific extension to the DOM, and is not supported by any other browsers (except Opera, I believe, who simulate it in order to improve compatibility with sites written for IE).

You can use things like `x.children` and `x.childNodes`, or `x.getElementById()` and `x.getElementsByTagName()` to reference elements below the current one in the tree, depending on your usage. I suspect in this case `x.children` is what you're after.

Comment: Good answer!  Works in IE and FF.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this answer has helped way more people than alot of other answers with 400 votes. It deserves more :)

Answer (score 1):

`all` would be the name of an array. It is not a native javascript keyword.

You may want to look at [childNodes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/childNodes) instead.