# .all function is not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, mozilla

```
function expand(entity) {
            alert("expand");
        var oImage;
        var children;
        if (entity.hasChildNodes())
 {
    children= entity.childNodes;
   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
   {
   };
 };

oImage = children.all["image"];
        oImage.src = entity.imageOpen;

        if (typeof(entity.imageOpen) == "undefined")
            oImage.src = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/MinusSignBlackSilver.gif";

        for(i=0; i < entity.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if(entity.childNodes(i).tagName == "DIV") {
                entity.childNodes(i).style.display = "block"
            }
        }
        entity.open = "true"
    }
```

`.all` is not woking in Mozilla.
What function do I use in place of `.all` so that it can work both in IE and Mozilla?

Comment: You are not using `all` in the code...

Comment: by mistake i posted wrong code. Now I edited the code.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666234/firefox-javascript-why-does-all-not-work , i think it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If the element has the id `image`, you can use the `getElementById` method:

```
oImage = document.getElementById("image");
```