# What is the alternative for .all in javascript or .all alternate in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, internet-explorer-11

Hi i have an application which was supressed with compatibility mode IE-5. In that application they are using **.all** API in javascript to fetch an particular element from DOM It was working fine. but in Windows 10 Machine when i use the same application in IE-11 browser it didn't support **.all** . So kindly let me know the alternative option for .all in javascript or jquery.

> Examples:1

```
JSP:   

    <Table  id="testtable">
     <tr> </tr>
     <tr> </tr>
     <tr id="testrow">
      <td> <FONT size=1 face="Verdana, Arial"> 
          <INPUT class=list maxLength=12 size=3 name=prime1> 
          </FONT> Test Data1
     </td>
      <td> <FONT size=1 face="Verdana, Arial"> 
          <INPUT class=list maxLength=12 size=3 name=prime2> 
          </FONT> Test Data2
      </td>
      <td> <FONT size=1 face="Verdana, Arial"> 
           <INPUT class=list maxLength=12 size=3 name=prime3> 
          </FONT> Test Data3
      </td>
      <td> <FONT size=1 face="Verdana, Arial"> 
           <INPUT class=list maxLength=12 size=3 name=prime4> 
          </FONT> Test Data4
      </td>
      <td> <FONT size=1 face="Verdana, Arial"> 
           <INPUT class=list maxLength=12 size=3 name=prime5> 
           </FONT> Test Data5
      </td>
      <td> <FONT size=1 face="Verdana, Arial"> 
           <INPUT class=list maxLength=12 size=3 name=prime6> 
           </FONT> Test Data6
       </td>
     </tr>
    </Table>


Js:

function tablesample (tableId,rowId)
 {
 var tab = document.getElementById(tableId);
 var row = tab.rows(rowId);
 var tdc ;
 var count ;
 var colcount = row.cells.length;
 for(var i=2;i<colcount;i++)
  {
   tdc = row.cells[i];
   count = tdc.all.length; 
  } 
 }
```

}

when the above js method Is triggered while reaching the line tdc.all.length; I got an issue "**Unable to get property "length" of undefined or null** ". It should give the length as 2 but it didn't. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox Javascript: Why does .all not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666234/firefox-javascript-why-does-all-not-work)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have updated the question with additional details. kindly advise.

Comment: Thanks  for your comments but my issue is different .

Comment: Thank but my problem is not about cross browsers. my issue is in IE only.

Comment: Now I am moving to Windows 10 browers. in that browser compatibility Mode option is not available so. it makes an problem ,so I would like to solve. Thanks

Comment: Thanks For you Help. My application is only using IE. not other browser. because its an old application.

Comment: Being cross browser simply means every browser supports that option.  But you are saying you don't want an option that works in IE, you are asking for an option that **only** works in IE?  That's completely illogical.

Comment: Because it was developed around the 10 years before. in that time they have code only IE in their mind. Now it creates problem. so help me to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.children` -- it's supported by all browsers, while `.all` is specific to old versions of IE.

MSDN says it's not supported starting with Internet Explorer 11.

As it's not supported `tdc.all` returns `undefined`. Then you do `undefined.length` which gives the error `Unable to get property "length" of undefined or null`.

Comment: Thanks @Danil Speransky . I have updated the above question with additional details. Kindly help me .

Comment: whats the alternative for  this help me

Comment: You may be looking for node.childNodes (property not function)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Comment: I tried both tdc.children and tdc.childNoes  but it gave the count as 1 instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tab = document.getElementById('testtable');
var row = tab.getElementsByTagName('tr')
var number_of_children = row.testrow.children.length;
```